# Is is possible to configure two external IP addresses to an nginx ingress controler on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, external-ip

I would like to provide two external IP depending on the environment of a namespace (dev or prod). My idea is to host the same fqdns on dev and prod namespaces. e.g. if the client resolves [www.mywebsite.lan](http://www.mywebsite.lan) on 192.168.171.1 then he is working on the dev environment and if he resolves on 192.168.171.10 he is targeting the production.

Be aware that I'm still a beginner on k8s and I think I've made some misakes or misunderstandings.

I have built two metallb ip-pools, with single IP addresses:

```
NAME              AUTO ASSIGN   AVOID BUGGY IPS   ADDRESSES
ac3-dev-ippool    true          false             ["192.168.171.1/32"]
ac3-prod-ippool   true          false             ["192.168.171.10/32"]
```

I have a nginx ingress controler (default configuration, excepted externalTrafficPolicy which is in Cluster mode and the appProtocol https enabled):

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE     IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ingress-nginx-controller-68fb8cf9cc-vkbfz   1/1     Running   2 (34h ago)   5d23h   10.244.3.2   ktux-130   <none>           <none>
```

and two ingresses on the prod and dev namespaces:

```
$ k get ingress -n ac3
NAME      CLASS   HOSTS               ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
ingress   nginx   www.mywebsite-prod.lan   192.168.171.1   80, 443   19h
$ k get ingress -n ac3-dev
NAME      CLASS   HOSTS               ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
ingress   nginx   www.mywebsite-dev.lan   192.168.171.1   80, 443   13d
```

But, as you can notice, both ingresses have got the same ip address (192.168.171.1) and I don't understand why. Note that it's working fine like that but I would like to be able to rename the vhosts to serve both [www.mywebsite.lan](http://www.mywebsite.lan).

Here is the ingresses configurations:

```
(...)
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: ac3  
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: ac3-prod-ippool
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-certs-mywebsite-prod
      hosts:
        - "www.mywebsite-prod.lan"
  rules:
    - host: "www.mywebsite-prod.lan"
      http:
(...)

---
(...)
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: ac3-dev
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: ac3-dev-ippool
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-certs-mywebsite-dev
      hosts:
        - "www.mywebsite-dev.lan"
  rules:
    - host: "www.mywebsite-dev.lan"
      http:
(...)
```

What's disturbing me is that the ingress controler only got one IP address from metallb :

```
$ k get svc -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller -oyaml | tail -5
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.171.1
```

I thought that it would get two ip addresses, one from each scope ?

The nginx ingress controler service is the default one :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.8.1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https-webhook
    port: 443
    targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: ClusterIP
```

So now my idea would be to create two ingress-controlers, one on namespace ac3 and another one on ac3-dev ? but I'm wondering if there is another way, easier and more "k8s compliant" to achieve my goal.

So please, k8s gurus, could you advise me or tell me where is my mistake ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The ip address associated with your Ingress resource is the address from the *ingress controller*; it's not something that is specific to the Ingress itself.

You're running the nginx ingress controller, so somewhere you have a Service of type LoadBalancer associated with the `ingress-nginx-controller-68fb8cf9cc-vkbfz` pod. The address assigned to that Service is what you'll see for all Ingress resources serviced by that ingress controller.

It doesn't make any sense to set the `metallb.universe.tf/address-pool` annotation on an Ingress; this is only meaningful on a Service resource.

If you want to expose an Ingress on  multiple addresses, you will need to assign multiple addresses to your ingress controller by creating multiple Service resources, one for each address.

### An example

I'm running k3s with the Traefik ingress controller. For this example, I have a Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: docker.io/traefik/whoami:latest
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
```

A Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
```

And finally an Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.k3s.virt
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example
            port:
              name: http
```

Out of the box, in the `kube-system` namespace, I have:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get service traefik
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
traefik          LoadBalancer   10.43.215.182   192.168.124.201   80:32271/TCP,443:32683/TCP   15d
```

You can see that the service has been assigned the address `192.168.124.201`; that's on what we'll call my "internal" address pool. Looking at my example application, we can see the ip address from the above service in the Ingress resource:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME      CLASS     HOSTS              ADDRESS           PORTS   AGE
example   traefik   example.k3s.virt   192.168.124.201   80      22m
```

And I can access the application at the given address:

```
$ curl -s http://192.168.124.201 -H host:example.k3s.virt
Hostname: example-758b5cd967-5gk7h
...
```

I have a "public" pool using range `192.168.126.0/24`; to expose Ingresses on that network, I would create a new Service in the same namespace as the ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: public
  name: traefik-public
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: web
  - name: websecure
    port: 443
    targetPort: websecure
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik-kube-system
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
  type: LoadBalancer
```

We can see that this gets assigned an address from the "public" pool:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get service traefik traefik-public
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                      AGE
traefik          LoadBalancer   10.43.215.182   192.168.124.201   80:32271/TCP,443:32683/TCP   15d
traefik-public   LoadBalancer   10.43.30.212    192.168.126.11    80:32452/TCP,443:32082/TCP   13m
```

Now now my application is accessible on *both* addresses:

```
$ curl -s http://192.168.124.201 -H host:example.k3s.virt
Hostname: example-758b5cd967-5gk7h
...
$ curl -s http://192.168.126.11 -H host:example.k3s.virt
Hostname: example-758b5cd967-5gk7h
...
```

Answer (score -2):

The process you have followed is correct, but requires some modifications. Metallb IP pools are different for `prod` and `dev` environments.The Nginx Ingress Controller is getting only one IP address from metal lb but you want to have different IP addresses for the same hostname depending on the environment.

Since the Nginx Controller is deployed in a single namespace, metal lb is assigning only one IP address to the controller which is expected behavior. Also, the ingress resources are having different hostnames(‘www.mywebsite-prod.lan’ and ‘www.mywebsite-dev.lan’ ) but they are pointing to the same IP address which is why you are not getting the expected behavior.

You can try the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Try **Dynamic Host Resolution** instead of specifying different hostnames for both the environments, you can use the same hostname (‘www.mywebsite.lan’).
2. Use Kubernetes features like **Configmap** or **env variables** to determine the environment within your application. Then, you can resolve the IP address of the service based on the environment.
3. Within Nginx Config dynamically routes traffic based on the hostname to different backend services associated with a different IP address.
4. For each environment, create separate kubernetes services pointing to different backend services. Ensure that each service is using the appropriate IP pool from metallb.

For example, a single Nginx Ingress Controller in the `‘ingress-nginx’` namespace with two kubernetes services, each with its own IP address assigned from Metallb pools. In the Nginx config, route the traffic based on the hostname to appropriate service.